# Is log(n) = Ω(n)?

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I believe it's not. The definition is that:

```
log(n) >= c*n for some n = x, and all n > x
```

The reason I think it's not is that the rate of growth of c*n = c. The rate of growth of log(n) = 1/n. So, as n-> infinity, the rate of growth of n approaches 0, whereas c, the rate of growth of c*n, is constant. Given that eventually log(n) will eventually grow slower than any n*c, where c > 0, n*c will outgrow log(n).

So, a few questions.

1. Can I assume c > 0 from the definition of big omega?
2. Is my above intuition correct?
3. I'm conflicted about my proof above. Because for very small c's, log(n) = cn very early, my assumption above implies that they would intersect again, which means log(n) = cn has more than one solution, which seems wrong.

I'm very confused and appreciate the help!

Comment: This question is a bit confusing to me because the omega notation is generally used to characterize *algorithms*, not abstract functions.  For example, there are algorithms that can compute `log(n)` (for a finite set of input values of `n`) in Ω(1) -- your FPU probably contains one in the form of a lookup table.

Comment: The omega notation is used to characterize the asymptotic growth of functions, so the question is absolutely correct. It does not characterize algorithms, but can describe the resource consumption (time, space, ...) of algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1- c cannot be 0 or negative, so you can assume that.

2- The growth of `log(n)` is lower than the growth of `n`, for every `n > 1`, for example. As Ω(n) is the set of functions that "grow more" than the function `f(n) = n`, log(n) is not Ω(n). But you could say n = Ω(log(n)), although that would not be an asymptotic tight bound.

3- The definition states that the inequality may be valid starting from one value `n0`. If some `n0` exists, you can say that. But in this case (log(n) = Ω(n)), it doesn't, because it must be valid for every `n >= n0`. And for any big value, log(n)'s growth is lower than n's growth.

Answer (score 1):

No, actually the opposite is true.

- A running time of `log(n)` function is `O(n)`

[read : upper bounded by some polynomial fn whose highest order term is `n`]

- and a `fn` having  running-time of `n` is `Ω(log(n))`

  [read : lower-bounded by some polynomial fn whose highest order term is `log(n)`]

Regarding your intuition, it's perfectly correct. `log(n)=cn` meets only at a single point.